# How true is the plot of 'Arrow' to the comic with regards to his origins and background?

Tags: arrow, arrowverse, comic-adaptation

While I've read a few of the [Green Arrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Arrow) comics, I honestly don't remember much of it, including anything about Oliver Queen's origins. Does he even have an origin story? How true is the plot of the [TV series, Arrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_%28TV_series%29), to the comic? Are there any similarities at all?

Comment: A major difference is that in the TV series there will be [no superpowered beings](http://www.comicbookmovie.com/fansites/JoshWildingNewsAndReviews/news/?a=66224).

Comment: Is flash not a super powered being?

Comment: @Oliver_C your comment has gone obsolete!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The TV show actually uses a similar origin story to the very first Green Arrow comics from the DC 'Golden Age'.

The only major difference is that in the comic, Oliver Queen was actually the boy's father, Green Arrow himself being Roy Harper.

Here is a quick rundown of the original comic book story from the [DC database](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Arrow_Origins):

> Roy Harper was a young boy whose parents had been killed in a plane
>   crash that stranded him on the isolated Lost Mesa; he had learned to
>   hunt to survive. (His father) Oliver Queen's museum was burned down by
>   criminals he had been fighting during an attempted robbery, and he
>   ventured to the Mesa as a means of finding a new lease on life.
>   Criminals followed him in search of rumored treasure and shot Harper's
>   only friend Quoag, forcing the man and boy to work together. They took
>   their code-names Green Arrow and Speedy from off-handed remarks the
>   thugs had made, and defeated them using bows and arrows. Discovery of
>   the treasure made them very wealthy, and they used that money to fund
>   their crime-fighting careers.

Comment: Thank you :) The Silver Age origin on that page has Queen as a billionaire playboy who falls from a cruise ship and is stranded on a deserted island ... So it appears to be a _conflation_ of multiple origin stories. (Also, from what I remember Roy Harper (Speedy, Red Arrow, Arsenal) was _adopted_ by Queen (Green Arrow).)

Comment: *"The TV show actually uses a similar origin story to the very first Green Arrow comics"* - Yet the following story summary doesn't really match the TV-show in many major points and the story from *coleopterist*'s comment seems much more similar.