# How much resemblance is there between the "Arrow" TV-series and the "Green Arrow" comics?

Tags: character, arrow, arrowverse, comic-adaptation

I have seen Arrow season 1, 2, 3 and am currently watching season 4. And in season 4 Oliver Queen changes his name from "Arrow" to "Green Arrow". Also meta-humans or mystic powers villains are appearing in the series. I have not read the Arrow comics.

So I was wondering if anyone can help me with some of my questions:

1. How much resemblance is there between the "Arrow" TV-series and the "Green Arrow" comics?
2. In comics, does "Arrow" fight with meta-humans and win? Is he that powerful or skilled?
3. In the comics, is both "Arrow" and "Green Arrow" used or only one?
4. Is there a "Team Arrow" in comics? If it exists, who is in it?

Comment: Related (if not even duplicate): [How true is the plot of 'Arrow' to the comic?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/8810/49)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Varies greatly depending on era. Green Arrow comics span decades, with different writers, multiverse plot lines, and different incarnations/reboots of the DC universe. In general, some things are keep the same, some are spiced up for tv formatting. There are Arrow-verse tie-in comic series that are closer to the show, naturally, while some aspects of the show are incorporated into the main DC universe (as of New 52, John Diggle was imported). One example, the Ra's Al Ghul/League of Assassins plot line is unique to the show. Ra's is Batman's rogue, not Green Arrow's. The mysterious Island origin is similar to the Judd Winick 2004 era comics. Felicity Smoak was a Firestorm character, not Green Arrow character.
2. Yes. Arrow can keep up with many super-powered enemies, but his stories and villains are more grounded than say Green Lanterns.
3. Green Arrow has had long term team-ups with various other superheroes like Black Canary, Green Lantern, the Justice League. He also had various *Robins* like Speedy/Arsenal/Red Arrow.
4. As far as supporting cast of non-superhero members supporting Green Arrow during caping, like Felicity and John do in the show, I am not sure. His extensive comic history would have to be looked at. For a nickname for the various sidekicks, there existed a "Team Arrow" starting in Green Arrow Vol. 3 (2001-2007) referring to Green Arrow and his sidekicks (Think Bat Family). In the New 52 universe, Green Arrow Vol. 5, the TV cast has essentially been incorporated, so is at least out of universe "Team Arrow". And then there is the Arrow Season 2.5 tie in comics, which are in continuity with the TV show.